# except and only

Tags: word-meaning, vocabulary, conjunctions

I found the following example in the Longman Dictionary:

> [except](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/except)
>   2 used to give the reason why something was not done or did not happen
>   **except (that)**
>   Liz would have run, except that she didn’t want to appear to be in a hurry.

Are "except" and "only" interchangeable in the example?

Comment: Please include the source of your examples, any research you previously done, and any other specific issues you uncovered in your research.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost right.

**except that** is [used to give a reason why something is not possible or true](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/except-that)

**only** is [used to show what is the single or main reason why something mentioned in the first part of the sentence cannot be performed or is not completely true](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/only)

Note that **that** is only required as a part of the **except that** idiom: it is not required with **only**. The two correct versions are:

> Liz would have run, **except that** she didn’t want to appear to be in a hurry.
>   Liz would have run, **only** she didn’t want to appear to be in a hurry.

In this context, both are equivalent in meaning to **but**. I would regard **only** as quite informal: I would use it in speech, but would be unlikely to write it.

Comment: It seems that Cambridge definition of "except that" is too narrow. It doesn't cover, for example, "I have earrings just like those, except they’re blue."

Comment: @Apollyon, I would say that the definition fits. The statement is "I have earrings just like those". In fact, the statement is not true, and the reason that it is not true is "they're blue".

Comment: The statement introduced by "except" makes "I have earrings just like those" not _completely_ true. So what really fits is the definition of "only."

Comment: Longman's [definition](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/except) of "except" is better than Cambridge's: _used to mention a fact that makes what you have just said seem less true_